# Using an “IF” statement for popping to two possible View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

Currently I just have a segue hooked up to a `UITableView` that pops to the next `UITableView` in the navigation stack.

What I need to do though now instead, is set up an **`if` statement** based on the text in the `UITableView` cell, **to decide which** of two possible **`UIViewController`s to pop** to.

**So `ViewController2` needs to be able to pop either":**

**- back to `ViewController1`**

***OR***

**- forward to `ViewController3`**

**based on the text in the `UITableView` cell that is populated by JSON.**

Can you help me out with that? Will post any code needed.  Thanks!

***Current ViewController:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;

    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"themes"]) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        // Get reference to destination view controller
        MRTViewController *tvc = (MRTViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
*Added code per @troops but still not sure how to pop to VC3*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringToCheck = @"AAA";
    if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:stringToCheck])
    {
        //Pop to VC1
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
    } else {
        //Pop to VC3, not sure what to put here


        // Pass the info
        tvc.spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        tvc.leaf = [tvc.spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tvc.buttonNumber = _buttonNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: At a higher level. It sounds like you want to be using the strategy pattern.

Comment: @chrimsonchris what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's a design pattern. Instead of your view controller deciding how to navigate, you would have another object, the "strategy" be responsible for determining this. Different types of items in your view model would have references to different strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check the cell's textLabel's string: If you really want to use segues and not the tableView's delegate method of: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` That's why I based my answer off what your initial question/code looks like.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringToCheck = @"AAA";

    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:stringToCheck])
    {
        // Pop to VC1
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Push to VC3
        MRTViewController3 *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourID"];

        tvc.spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        tvc.leaf = [tvc.spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tvc.buttonNumber = _buttonNumber;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I actually don't mind doing it not with segues, what approach would you say is better?

Comment: Use the delegate method: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: So delete the segue I currently have in my Storyboard, and then use the delegate method where I check `cell.textLabel.text`?

Comment: @Reez Yes sir, if you don't have more than 1 segue identifier there's no need to use prepareForSegue

Comment: Except I'm passing some data to the next view controller, so would I need to make sure I used prepareForSegue in that case?

Comment: Nope, you can pass the data in like this: `tvc.yourProperty = someVariable` then push the view controller.

Comment: Ok I added the info you said to, and think I'm like 90% there, but can't figure out how to add pop to VC3 code, can you give me some advice on that?  It seems different than the code I have to pop back to VC1.  Added code at the bottom of my original question for you to see what I have now.  Thanks!!

Comment: Please see my revised answer :) Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: For whatever reason, I'm getting a crash when it tries to pop to VC3, any ideas?  Here's the two logs

Comment: `Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UINavigationController.m:4912`

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: Failed to get popped view controller.`

Comment: May be better to just use an NSNotifcation and then pop to the `[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:2]`

Comment: What does the NSNotification part do?

Comment: You can add an observer on the 3rd view controller and listen for new data/objects when you post an NSNotification. You can pass an object directly in an NSNotification

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding which part your subbing that for, is it the part where I pass properties to the next controller or what exactly?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please see revised answer again

Comment: Getting an error on the `NSDictionary` line for `@"leaf":[spring.leafs' that I wasn't getting before.  Do I not need to do `tvc` before any of them?  Basically on that line its not recognizing `spring`

Comment: Nah, getting error `Collection element of type init is not an Objective C object` on the `NSDictionary` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56041/discussion-between-troop231-and-reez).

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate method, get cell, compare text.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Your String"])
    {
          //Pop or present view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm having a hard time figuring out the code necessary to pop to `VC3`, can you give me some guidance on that?  I can pop back to `VC1` just fine, but having a hard time popping forward to `VC3`